Can I use Blazemeter test data into a Jmeter property?
I have a Jmeter script running in Blazemeter with Jmeter properties.
Now I wanted to have a property changing during the run. So I am trying to pass test data into a Jmeter property by referencing ${market}. But what happens is that I get the literal "${market}" instead of a random value from the list. Am I doing this the wrong way?
enter image description here
When I set a value directly like "PT" or "DE" it works fine. But I wanted it to change during the run.
PS.: I am kind of newbie in Jmeter and Blazemeter.

I don't think this is a correct way of setting and updating a JMeter Property, take a look at Live Remote Control for JMeter Properties feature to see how you can update a property value in the runtime

Add one or more properties to the JMeter Properties section of your test configuration.

Start your test.

When the test report appears, click the Run Time Control button at the top-right and click Remote Control.


The Remote Control Live window appears, listing all JMeter properties available for updating. This by default includes all scenarios in all locations. For more details, see Advanced Features.


Enter a new value for each property you want to update and click Send to update the property on all engines.



If you want just to to send a random value from a list for each request - take a look at i.e. __RandomFromMultipleVars() function
